# Does such a matrix exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let $R^n$ be a real vector space with the standard inner product and $\alpha$ a unit vector.

Can we find a symmetric and orthogonal real matrix with the first column being the vector $\alpha$?

Comment: Since we're talking real matrices, you may as well say orthogonal instead of unitary. It is more common. Or, if we are talking complex matrices, you probably want to say Hamiltonian instead of symmetric.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: An $n\times n$ matrix has $n^2$ elements. If it is symmetric, then $\frac{n(n+1)}2$ of them are distinct. You have specified values for $n$ of those by selecting $\alpha$. Othogonality of the columns means that the inner product of any two columns (which may be picked in $\binom n 2 = \frac{n(n-1)}2$ ways) is $0$. That gives $\frac {n(n-1)}2$ equations in $\frac {n(n+1)}2 - n$ unknowns.